# Vimdiff and git all at once

Tags: vim, git, diff, vimdiff

I use vimdiff as my difftool with git.

Let's say that I've changed twelve files. The problem is that sometimes I run `git diff` and around the fourth or fifth file I see something that I want to edit/change. Sometimes I need to make a few more changes outside of this. The problem is that I can't just `:qa` and go back to hacking,  because there are six or seven more diffs that pop up in vimdiff. It gets really tedious to `:qa` all of these files without looking every time that I want to abort a git diff.

Is there any way to set up vimdiff as git's difftool such that all of the diffs open in the same vim instance, e.g. in separate tabs?

Comment: I never had an idea why tabs were introduced and how they could be used in a sensible way. This is the first use-case where tabs actually would make sense.

Comment: I agree. The only real use case I've seen for tabs is when I want a similar group of buffers open in a different configuration of windows; i.e. one tab has a header and a source file in a split, while another tab has the source and a makefile in a vertical split. Or something. And sometimes it's nice to have a "stack of windows", i.e. you're editing four files in some splits and you want to make a quick edit to your vimrc, `:tabe ~/.vimrc` followed by `:bd` is a nice combo.

Comment: Did it for me http://stackoverflow.com/q/2428051/168034

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the vim plugins published [here](http://www.xenomachina.com/2012/02/multi-diff-with-vim-andor-git.html). Then you just need to set the difftool:

```
[multidiff]
  tool = vd -f
```

As an alternative application I would suggest `meld`, which will show you modified files - you can then select just the files who's diffs you want to see.

See the [screenshot here](http://meldmerge.org/features.html) for an example.

Further to Marcos useful comment, as a third (manual alternative) if you want to use `vimdiff` I would recommend following `meld`'s strategy in a script (possibly `python`):

- use `git diff-files --name-status` and `git diff-index --name-status --cached HEAD` to identify files that need to be examined.
- Get cached versions of these files and place in `/tmp/`
- Open all of these files - the changed files and their cached versions - at once in `vimdiff` - though most likely not possible in the sense that you require- see below.

However, as `vimdiff` itself doesn't seem to handle multiple diff tabs natively I recommend one of my other suggestions above.

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment, since it does not answer the question at all.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Marco - I hope my edits have improved my answer.

Comment: They did definitely. This is not what I would call elegant, but it seems to work. I'll give it two weeks of testing if this is a practical solution. Thanks for sharing, this vim “invasion” while diffing always bothered me.

Answer (score 4):

A quite simple workaround is to add this option in your ~/.gitconfig file

```
[difftool]
    tool = vimdiff $LOCAL $REMOTE
    prompt = true
```

That way before each file comparison, you are prompted and have the possibility to skip a file  by answering 'no' or abort the file comparison with Ctrl+C

Example:

```
$ git difftool
Viewing: 'file1.js'
Launch 'vimdiff' [Y/n]: y
2 files to edit

Viewing: 'file2.js'
Launch 'vimdiff' [Y/n]: n
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use. It requires that you use [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)

`[alias]
    dt = "!f() { vim -p $(git diff --name-only) +\"tabdo Gdiff $@\" +tabfirst; }; f"`

`git dt` will then open each diff pair in a separate tab. Then `:tabclose` to close a single pair, or `:qa` to exit.

[source](https://gist.github.com/dpwright/2873132)

Comment: Will this work with multiple refs, instead of comparing against the working files?

Comment: No since this works by openning all the working files and running Gdiff on each tab.

Comment: Really liked this though. Very smart solution. Congrats.

Answer (score 2):

There's a much simpler solution that's not posted yet.

Add the following to your `~/.gitconfig` -

```
[difftool]
    trustExitCode = true
```

Now you can run `:cq` at any time during the process to stop diffing more files.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following script to achieve the behaviour git difftoll + vimdiff provides, but using tabs:

```
#!/bin/bash

commit1=$1
commit2=$2

files=`git diff ${commit1} ${commit2} --name-only`

cmd="set nosplitright | set nobackup | set noswapfile"

EXE="| silent exe"

for f in $files; do
    if [ -z "$commit2" ]; then
        cmd+="$EXE ':tabnew $f'"
    else
        cmd+="$EXE ':tabnew | f <${commit2}>/${f} | setlocal buftype=nofile | 0read ! git show ${commit2}:$f'"
    fi
    cmd+="$EXE ':0 | filetype detect'"
    cmd+="$EXE ':vnew | f <${commit1}>/${f} | setlocal buftype=nofile | 0read ! git show ${commit1}:$f'"
    cmd+="$EXE ':0 | filetype detect'"
    cmd+="$EXE ':windo diffth'"
done
cmd+="$EXE 'bd 1 | tabfirst'"

vim -c "$cmd"
```

Call it like this:
`vimgd <commit1> <commit2>`